# Jquery: Form submitting not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

So I'm trying to submit a form in jquery to hide or show stuff.

But it doesn't work after submitting again.

Html:

```
<form id="filters" href="#">
        <table id="filter" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Show/Hide</th><th>Column</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkNumber" value="1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    Account Number
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
   $('#filters').submit(function() {
       if ($('input[name=checkNumber]').attr('checked') == true) {
           $('input[name=search_account]').show("normal");      
       }
      else if ($('input[name=checkNumber]').attr('checked') !== true) {
           $('input[name=search_account]').hide("normal");
       }
           return false;
    }); 

});
```

I've tried so many other ways, but it all works the same. I submit, it hides the right input tag but when I resubmit to show it, it doesn't work.

It also doesn't work if I submit it with the checkbox checked.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should rather try `else` instead of `else if`.

Comment: Looking again at your code - what exactly are you trying to achieve? Once the form is submitted, it will reload the page, won't it?

Comment: No it doesn't reload the page, it just submits the jquery to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that your html is invalid as well.  doesn't have href attribute, you should use action instead. But it seems that in your case you don't need a form at all.

What I think you might want to achieve is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="filter" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Show/Hide</th><th>Column</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkNumber" value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Account Number
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input name="search_account" style="display: none;" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#filter input[name=checkNumber]").click(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("input[name=search_account]").show();
                    } else {
                        $("input[name=search_account]").hide();
                    }
                }); 
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.on('submit',function(){ your code here and check your code in the else if part. you should use != not !==});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 else if ($('input[name=checkNumber]').attr('checked') != true) {
           $('input[name=search_account]').hide("normal");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should use

```
$('input[name=checkNumber]').is(':checked')
```

instead of

```
$('input[name=checkNumber]').attr('checked')
```

Comment: Tried this already, doesn't work. I'm using this library, does it make a difference? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>